# Checksum Algorithm Producing Unpredictable Results

Tags: groovy, checksum, unsigned-integer

I'm working on a checksum algorithm, and I'm having some issues. The kicker is, when I hand craft a "fake" message, that is substantially smaller than the "real" data I'm receiving, I get a correct checksum. However, against the real data - the checksum does not work properly.

Here's some information on the incoming data/environment:

- This is a groovy project (see code below)
- All bytes are to be treated as unsigned integers for the purpose of checksum calculation

  - You'll notice some finagling with shorts and longs in order to make that work.
- The size of the real data is 491 bytes.
- The size of my sample data (which appears to add correctly) is 26 bytes
- None of my hex-to-decimal conversions are producing a negative number, as best I can tell
- Some bytes in the file are not added to the checksum. I've verified that the switch for these is working properly, and when it is supposed to - so that's not the issue.
- My calculated checksum, and the checksum packaged with the real transmission always differ by the same amount.
- I have manually verified that the checksum packaged with the real data is correct.

Here is the code:

```
// add bytes to checksum
public void addToChecksum( byte[] bytes) {
    //if the checksum isn't enabled, don't add
    if(!checksumEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    long previouschecksum =  this.checksum;

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        byte[] tmpBytes = new byte[2];
        tmpBytes[0] = 0x00;
        tmpBytes[1] = bytes[i];

        ByteBuffer tmpBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(tmpBytes);

        long computedBytes = tmpBuf.getShort();
        logger.info(getHex(bytes[i]) + " = " + computedBytes);
        this.checksum += computedBytes;
    }

    if(this.checksum < previouschecksum) {
        logger.error("Checksum DECREASED: " + this.checksum);
    }
    //logger.info("Checksum: " + this.checksum);
}
```

If anyone can find anything in this algorithm that could be causing drift from the expected result, I would greatly appreciate your help in tracking this down.

Comment: Quick question... Why not use md5, sha or some other proven hashing algorithm? Ie: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/256001

Comment: Without diving into details of your implementation, why aren't you using any well-known, established and good enough checksum algorithms like CRC, MD5 or SHA (from trivial to close to ideal)?

Comment: Well, first let me state that I don't get to determine which checksum algoritm is used. So, that's a moot point. I have to conform to protocol - no option about that. Second, it was done to conserve bandwidth. With the amount of data we're moving - using this method translates to real dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a line in your code where you reset your `this.checksum`.

This way, you should alway get a `this.checksum > previouschecksum`, right? Is this intended?

Otherwise I can't find a flaw in your above code. Maybe your 'this.checksum' is of the wrong type (short for instance). This could rollover so that you get negative values.

here is an example for such a behaviour

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
short checksum = 0
byte[] bytes = new byte[491]
def count = 260
for (def i=0;i<count;i++) {
    bytes[i]=255
}
bytes.each { b ->
    byte[] tmpBytes = new byte[2];
    tmpBytes[0] = 0x00;
    tmpBytes[1] = b;
    ByteBuffer tmpBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(tmpBytes);
    long computedBytes = tmpBuf.getShort();
    checksum += computedBytes
    println "${b} : ${computedBytes}"
}
println checksum +"!=" + 255*count
```

just play around with the value of the 'count' variable which somehow corresponds to the lenght of your input.

Comment: This method is only a part of a larger class. And yes, `this.checksum` should *always* be greater than `previouschecksum`. I had that line to detect the possibility that I was generating negative numbers. It was strictly a debugging tactic. Also, `this.checksum` is a long.

Comment: 491 bytes sin't too much. Have you already `println`ed the results of each iteration?

Comment: Well, 491 bytes may not sound like much, but it amounts to about 80 commands. I'd love to share to have someone else check my math, but it's proprietary stuff. :-\

Answer (score 0):

Your checksum will keep incrementing until it rolls over to being negative (as it is a signed long integer)

You can also shorten your method to:

```
public void addToChecksum( byte[] bytes) {
  //if the checksum isn't enabled, don't add
  if(!checksumEnabled) {
    return;
  }

  long previouschecksum =  this.checksum;
  this.checksum += bytes.inject( 0L ) { tot, it -> tot += it & 0xFF }

  if(this.checksum < previouschecksum) {
    logger.error("Checksum DECREASED: " + this.checksum);
  }
  //logger.info("Checksum: " + this.checksum);
}
```

But that won't stop it rolling over to being negative.  For the sake of saving 12 bytes per item that you are generating a hash for, I would still suggest something like MD5 which is know to work is probably better than rolling your own...  However I understand sometimes there are crazy requirements you have to stick to...

Comment: Yeah, fortunately I'm not running into a situation where the sum is rolling over. When I do my addition it's just less than it is supposed to be, which is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @Matt do you have an example byte array that causes the error you're seeing?